# Has Jeppesen announced plans to stop supporting the Microsoft platform for Flight Deck Pro?

Tags: efb

I heard a rumor around the water cooler recently that Jeppesen plans to drop support for Microsoft and have continued development of Flight Deck Pro EFB software only available on Apple. Has anyone seen anything that could confirm or refute this?

Answer (score 1):

Only 6 months ago Jeppesen [announced a common interface](https://ww1.jeppesen.com/company/newsroom/articles.jsp?newsURL=news/newsroom/2016/FliteDeck_Pro_iOS9WIN10_NRL.jsp) for iOS 9 and Windows 10.

And why would they deliberately lose their airline customers that use Windows? The integrated Class 3 [EFB's on Boeing planes](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/aero_23/EFB.pdf) for example, run Windows.

> The open architecture of the EFB
> Class 3 system will allow airlines
> (or third-party suppliers) to develop
> software for the Microsoft Windows
> processor using a software development kit provided by Boeing and
> Jeppesen.

Regarding the FliteDeck, only [a couple of weeks ago](https://www.airlinesoftware.net/news/3579/foreflight-and-jeppesen-announce-strategic-alliance):

> **ForeFlight and Jeppesen Announce Strategic Alliance**
>
> Jeppesen and ForeFlight will work together on a next-generation release of FliteDeck Pro for both iOS and **Windows** that will deliver a combination of the familiar capabilities in FliteDeck Pro and significant features and functionality from ForeFlight Mobile.

Comment: Thanks for getting this helpful answer posted before too many people could vote to close it.